# Evolution: Work week Print Layout only prints 5-days and not 7-Days

Tags: evolution

Some of us work 7 days (well, we like to 'map out' out week 7 days) and not 5 days. I used to like MS Outlook (pre Vista) for being able to print out my planned forthcoming 7 days scheduled week and throw a printed copy on my office door. Now I've moved 100% Ubuntu I like using Evolution as it is a 'close' clone to MS Outlook and really does everything I need. I don't really want to move/change to another Diary application, and don't really want add any external functionality (Google apps etc).
When I come to print out the 'Work Week' in Evolution, my 7-day screen view only appears as a 5-day view, pretty annoying and from all the Prefs, I cannot find a way to print out 7-day view other than an alternative work week view, which simply doesn't show the days in detail.

Is this an App design fault, an omission, or something that can't be done in Evo 3.6x compared to MS Outlook (ala pre Vista) or something I'm missing as a whole, as I cannot find any templates etc to meet my needs? FYI, I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 with Evo 3.6x.

Comments on how/if it can be changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply select all days as work days from the preferences. After this, your work week should show 7 days and I guess you should be able to print it as 7 days.

Comment: This does not work for me with 3.44.4-0ubuntu2